# Fetching Button from the Dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

i have added the created buttons to the `NSMutabledictionary`,i want to just iterate the `NSDictionary` and store the button in one variable.

```
  UIButton *word= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  .
  .
  .
  [self.buttonsDict setObject:word forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rownumber]];

  for (int j = 0; j<self.buttonsDict; j++) {

int index = [self.buttonsDict objectForKey:rownumber]; 
 }
```

instead of index what should i use to retrieve the button from the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are wanting to iterate over all the keys in the dictionary? The simplest way - not the fastest, for that you'd want to use NSDictionary's [keyEnumerator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/keyEnumerator:) - to do this would be to iterate over all the keys and get each button using each key.

```
for (NSNumber *key in self.buttonsDict.allKeys) {
    UIButton *button = [self.buttonsDict objectForKey:key];
    // Do whatever with the button
}
```